# When I teleport to a different map, does the time on the original map stop?

Tags: the-riftbreaker

During the campaign of *The Riftbreaker*, you can jump between different maps. What happens to your base(s) on the other maps while you are away? Does the time stop on them? Or do you need to go back regularly to check in on them and make sure that the defenses are still standing?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

All the creatures are frozen in time while you aren't present. The same applies to natural disasters: There won't be any while you are away, and any ongoing disasters will pause and continue  as soon as you return. So you don't need to worry about your other bases while you are away. You will find them in the exact same condition in which you left them.

However, production does **not** pause. Miners will keep using up their mineral deposits and produce minerals. Processing plants will keep converting resources. Non-regenerative power plants will keep consuming resources. Even harvesters will keep producing resources based on what their average yield was at the moment you left the map.

Unfortunately this can not be exploited if you run out of resources while being attacked. Rift-jumping gets disabled as soon as an attack countdown starts and doesn't get enabled until the attackers have been repelled.

Comment: It can be exploited to give you large amounts of risk-free resources. You can build an outpost with tons of wind generators alongside a few resource synthesisers and then jump away. The outpost will give you steady Ironium and Carbonium resources that never deplete. You don't need to build any walls or towers and can channel all the energy into resources.